# Can someone tell me whats wrong with this script 

Tags: jquery, attr

```
$(this).siblings("property2").hide().child("select").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

This is supposed to access the sibling "property2" of a clicked button and hide it. After that it will access the child "select" of "property2" and add a disabled attribute to "select".

But this is not working. Help please ... thanks!

Comment: Can you please post you HTML here..

Comment: @aveson is your chaining sequence right , can you post the html

Comment: Indeed please post HTML because a plain jQuery line can be successful on the right document or fail on the wrong document. To be fair and disregarding explicit syntax errs, we should be able to see the target document to know what is being programmed against! Or paste it into http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).siblings(".property2").hide().children("select").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

1. `child` should be replaced with `children()`

If you are using `property2` then you are trying to select elements with tag name `property2`. If you  want to access by classname then it will be `.property2`.

If you want to remove the disabled property then you can use `.removeAttr("disabled")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `property2` is a class, and that the select is a direct descendant of that element:

```
$(this)
    .siblings('.property2')
    .hide()
    .children("select")
    .attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).siblings(".property2").hide().children().attr("disabled","disabled");
```

did it ... ^^